# Get rows with same id and must have certain values combined

Tags: sql, select

I've got two tables as follows:

```
TableA
------------
a_id
a_attribute


TableB
------------
b_id
b_attribute
```

Data:

```
a_id    a_attribute
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         4
2         5
2         6


b_id    b_attribute
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         2
2         3
3         4
3         5
3         6
```

I'm trying to figure out how to match it so if b_id has the b_attribute values of 1,2,3 it will match a_id 1 and if b_attribute has values of 4,5,6 it should match a_id 2.

In this case I would want the output to be:

```
b_id    a_id
1       1
3       2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read about `JOIN` and `UNION`. You likely will need to use both of those here.

Comment: Although not really required for this problem, it's always good to specify which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of shared attributes is fixed maybe joining the tables on the attribute columns and filtering on count might work. Something like:

```
SELECT b.b_id, a.a_id FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.a_attribute = b.b_attribute
GROUP BY a.a_id, b.b_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

This would give the correct output for the example data you provided.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance on the topic, but does that mean it's returning every a_id and b_id where 3 rows have been found where a matching symptom exists?

Comment: @user2989484 Yes. It will return only those rows that have exactly three shared attributes even if one of the two tables has more than three attributes.

Comment: All right, even though it's helpful, it doesn't completely solve my problem, because I need it to be a combination of attributes, (ie. 1,2,3 or 4,5,6 and might in the future be for more than three (13,14,15,16). I appreciate your help though!